# juju bootstrap fails with a local environment, why?

Tags: juju

Each time I try to bootstrap juju using a local enviroment it fails starting the `juju-db-braiam-local` script as follows:

```
$ sudo juju --debug --verbose bootstrap
2013-10-20 02:28:53 INFO juju.provider.local environprovider.go:32 opening environment "local"
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.provider.local environ.go:210 found "10.0.3.1" as address for "lxcbr0"
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.provider.local environ.go:234 checking 10.0.3.1:8040 to see if machine agent running storage listener
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.provider.local environ.go:237 nope, start some
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:87 Uploading tools for [raring precise]
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools build.go:109 looking for: juju
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools build.go:150 checking: /usr/bin/jujud
2013-10-20 02:28:53 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:156 found existing jujud
2013-10-20 02:28:53 INFO juju.environs.tools build.go:166 target: /tmp/juju-tools243949228/jujud
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools build.go:217 forcing version to 1.14.1.1
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools build.go:37 adding entry: &tar.Header{Name:"FORCE-VERSION", Mode:420, Uid:0, Gid:0, Size:8, ModTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:278894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}, Typeflag:0x30, Linkname:"", Uname:"ubuntu", Gname:"ubuntu", Devmajor:0, Devminor:0, AccessTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:278894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}, ChangeTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:278894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}}
2013-10-20 02:28:53 DEBUG juju.environs.tools build.go:37 adding entry: &tar.Header{Name:"jujud", Mode:493, Uid:0, Gid:0, Size:19179512, ModTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:274894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}, Typeflag:0x30, Linkname:"", Uname:"ubuntu", Gname:"ubuntu", Devmajor:0, Devminor:0, AccessTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:274894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}, ChangeTime:time.Time{sec:63517832933, nsec:274894120, loc:(*time.Location)(0x108fda0)}}
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools storage.go:106 built 1.14.1.1-raring-amd64 (4196kB)
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools storage.go:112 uploading 1.14.1.1-precise-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools storage.go:112 uploading 1.14.1.1-raring-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:29 reading tools with major version 1
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:34 filtering tools by version: 1.14.1.1
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:37 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.1.1-precise-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.1.1-raring-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.boostrap bootstrap.go:57 bootstrapping environment "local"
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:29 reading tools with major version 1
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:34 filtering tools by version: 1.14.1.1
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:37 filtering tools by series: precise
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:41 reading v1.* tools
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.1.1-precise-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.environs.tools storage.go:61 found 1.14.1.1-raring-amd64
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.provider.local environ.go:395 create mongo journal dir: /home/braiam/.juju/local/db/journal
2013-10-20 02:28:55 DEBUG juju.provider.local environ.go:401 generate server cert
2013-10-20 02:28:55 INFO juju.provider.local environ.go:421 installing service juju-db-braiam-local to /etc/init
2013-10-20 02:28:56 ERROR juju.provider.local environ.go:423 could not install mongo service: exec ["start" "juju-db-braiam-local"]: exit status 1 (start: Job failed to start)
2013-10-20 02:28:56 ERROR juju supercommand.go:282 command failed: exec ["start" "juju-db-braiam-local"]: exit status 1 (start: Job failed to start)
error: exec ["start" "juju-db-braiam-local"]: exit status 1 (start: Job failed to start)
```

What is the reason for this error and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;dr: you don't have enought space availble. Make at least 500MB availble in your home partition.

---

Well, I started to poke around and found that the script fails executing `service juju-db-braiam-local start`. When ran manually it fails too. Checking the contents I found this:

```
description "juju state database"
author "Juju Team <juju@lists.ubuntu.com>"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
normal exit 0

limit nofile 65000 65000
limit nproc 20000 20000

exec /usr/bin/mongod --auth --dbpath=/home/braiam/.juju/local/db --sslOnNormalPorts --sslPEMKeyFile '/home/braiam/.juju/local/server.pem' --sslPEMKeyPassword ignored --bind_ip 0.0.0.0 --port 37017 --noprealloc --syslog --smallfiles
```

Per error code, the fails is withing the `exec` instruction, so I ran it manually. It apparently writes to the syslog so I found the reason:

```
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] options: { auth: true, bind_ip: "0.0.0.0", dbpath: "/home/braiam/.juju/local/db", noprealloc: true, port: 37017, smallfiles: true, sslOnNormalPorts: true, sslPEMKeyFile: "/home/braiam/.juju/local/server.pem", sslPEMKeyPassword: "<password>", syslog: true }
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] journal dir=/home/braiam/.juju/local/db/journal
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] 
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] Please make at least 422MB available in /home/braiam/.juju/local/db/journal or use --smallfiles
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] 
Oct 20 02:41:05 vm-2 mongod.37017[5159]: Sun Oct 20 02:41:05 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 15926 Insufficient free space for journals, terminating
```

There it's, apparently mongodb doesn't read the --smallfiles that is at the end of the script... weird. Freeing up 422MB should have fixed the issue, but mongodb should be able to start either way.

Invesigating futher, I discovered that mongodb ignores the `--smallfiles` completely while used with other paramethers. I've opened a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mongodb/+bug/1242237) about this, **the way to fix it easier is make more space available.**